# What is Fatal error: Invalid opcode 244/8/4 , what is the number(244/8/4) meaning?

Tags: php

I have search alot on internet and i need to know what does it mean.

oprating on php 5.4

Linux centOS 6.5

ioncubloader 4.7

error came on one of the modules on line 0.
Invalid opcode 244/8/4.

Comment: I hope you have not eaten your code and if not then you can show some code please!

Comment: That looks like you're using an opcode cache (eAccellerator, ioncube, etc) that is not compatible with the version of PHP you are running.

Answer (score -1):

I faced that problem in linux before but now solve,

**eAccelerator** may cause such a problem,
The eAccelerator is very old and unmaintained. You should upgrade to a newer version of PHP and use one of the opcode caching systems like XCache or WinCache.

I made it work by disabling eAccelerator, but server will be slow. use the suggested altenative above. see [documantation](http://wiki.typo3.org/Opcode_Cache)